# Producer and consumer using semaphore in Linux c

Tags: c, linux, semaphore, shared-memory, processor

Follows are my codes:

```
#include ...
sem_t mutex;
sem_t empty;
sem_t full;
int main()
{
    int shmid_arr;
    int shmid_get;
    int shmid_set;
    int *shmaddr = 0;
    int *shm_get_addr;
    int *shm_set_addr;
    shmid_arr = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, 20 * sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT|0600);
    shmid_get = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT|0600);
    shmid_set = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT|0600);
    **shmid_get = 0;
    **shmid_set = 0;
    sem_init(&mutex, 1 , 1 );
    sem_init(&full, 1 , 0 );
    sem_init(&empty, 1 , 20 );
    printf("sem_init\n");
    if(fork() == 0)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while(i<20)
        {
            sem_wait(&empty);
            sem_wait(&mutex);
            shm_set_addr = (int *)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
            shmaddr = (int *)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
            shmaddr[*shm_set_addr%20] =  i + 1;
            printf("produce %d\n", i+1)
            (* shm_set_addr)++;
            i++;
            shmdt(shmadrr);
            shmdt(shm_set_addr);
            sem_post(&mutex);
            sem_post(&full);
        }
        sleep(10);
        printf("Producer is over\n");
        exit(0);
    }else{
        while(1)
            {
                sem_wait(&full);
                sem_wait(&mutex);
                shm_get_addr = (int *)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
                shmaddr = (int *)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
                printf("consumer get %d\n",shmaddr[*shm_get_addr%20]);
                (*shm_get_addr)++;
                shmdt(shmadrr);
                shmdt(shm_get_addr);
                sem_post(&mutex);
                sem_post(&empty);
                sleep(1);
            }
        printf("consumer over\n");
        exit(0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I set three semaphores including `full`, `empty`, and `mutex`. `empty` is initialized to `20`, `full` is initialized to `0` and `mutex` is initialized to `1`.

I put `P(empty)` in front of producer critical section and `V(full)` after it using `P(mutex)m,V(mutex)` to lock. I put `P(full)` in front of consumer critical section and `V(empty)` after it using `P(mutex),V(mutex)` to lock. And I use `shm` to set and get shared memory.

It should get a result that producer produce and consumer consume. But my program never run a consumer producer processor. It confused me a lot. Did I use semaphore in wrong way? Or did I set shared memory in wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

There is couple of things that you should fix.

Semaphores must also be in shared memory, so you have to do something like this in the parent process:

```
mutex_memid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(sem_t), IPC_CREAT|0600);
```

and then `shmat` them in both, parent and child, processes.

```
mutex = (sem_t *)shmat(mutex_memid, NULL, 0);
```

You don't need to attach and detach shared memory every time you use it, so you can `shmat` before `while` loops and `shmdt` once you are done working with shared memory (outside of loops).

You don't need to store `shm_get_addr` and `shm_set_addr` since these variables are not used by both processes in your example.